# Why I am not getting any value back from the function?

Tags: c, string, reversing

Could you please tell me why I am not getting any value back from the function below?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned int length ;
    char * data ;
} String ;


String reverse(String this){

    String that;
    that=this;
    int i,j;
    j=that.length-1;
    char myc[that.length+1];

    for(i=0; i < that.length; i++, j--) {
         myc[i]=that.data[j];
    }
    myc[i+1]='\0';

    that.data= myc ;

    return that;
}
int main()
{
    String myStr;
    String myStrA;
    myStr.data= "This one is beautiful";
    myStr.length=21;

    String myStr2= reverse(myStr);

    printf("\n\nmy text before reverse :  %s \n", myStr.data);
    printf("\n\nmy text after reverse :  %s \n", myStr2.data);

    return 0;
}
```

// reverse function supposed to return back a reversed string but it does not

Comment: `char myc[that.length+1];` is assigned to a member of your struct, but that's local memory. Use `strdup` instead.

Comment: @EugeneSh. `that` isn't an issue. The struct is copied. the issue is the local VLA.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oh. Missed the point of it being struct rather than array.

Comment: Passing structs by value is usually not a good idea. Pass as pointer and apply const correctness.

Comment: In function `reverse`, the assignment `that.data = myc` is a bug which might lead to undefined behavior once outside the function, since `myc` is a local array hence not viable outside the scope of this function.

Answer (score 2):

in `reverse`

```
char myc[that.length+1];

for(i=0; i < that.length; i++, j--) {
     myc[i]=that.data[j];
}
myc[i+1]='\0';

that.data= myc ;   // <=== NO!!
```

you're assigning a *local VLA* to your return value, thus hiding the "return local array" warning (bad luck) that you would have got if you had returned the array directly.

So you lose the value as soon as the function returns because it goes out of scope, and the memory is reused by the program (undefined behaviour).

So you should copy the data so the memory is globally allocated with `that.data = strdup(myc)`;

or even better: don't create a VLA but allocate directly, which saves a copy, and you can safely assign `myc` now:

```
char *myc = malloc(that.length+1);
```

(and free it when not needed anymore)

Answer (score -4):

The code is NOT fine, I believe the issue is that you are compiling using g++ as you have the "this" keyword. Compile with GCC and then "this" will not be a keyword but an identifier. C++ is OOP which is why "this" is a keyword.

However other comments mention one problem and that is with the "this.data= myc". The array "myc" is declared on the scope not the heap so it has undefined behavior and could point to something completely different when the stack changes. Create the array on the heap instead or in the global scope.

Comment: Why do call the code "fine" and then writes that the code has a serious bug?

Comment: It would be a discrimination towards a buggy code to not call it "fine"!

Comment: I was stating fine meaning that the code works. This is why I clarified below that the problem pointed out by other people is an issue that must be solved as its undefined behavior. Keep your nickers on

Comment: I don't get it. You say: "I was stating fine meaning that the code works" How can you say that code with undefined behavior work? Sorry but it makes no sense.

Comment: The code does work when compiled with my version of GCC and does what is intended. However if this program was further developed obviously serious problems would arise. As stated when I said the program was "fine" I was referring to that the program works not that the program is right and under the right circumstances some compilers may produce binaries in the codes current state that do not run correctly. I don't understand why you and everyone else tries to cause a problem or an argument over answers when I have clarified that him doing that is a mistake.

Comment: and when I was writing this post I missed the obvious mistake and that is why I wrote the second paragraph and I didn't remove "The code is fine" as I clarified the mistake below.

Comment: Then remove it! Code with UB is never "fine" - it never "works". That's what UB is all about - no one knows what will happen. It may appear to do what it should on one system and fail completely on another.